# Mailer not sending in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I want to send email in my Rails app but I don't know why the email not sending to email destination, whereas in my log the email sending. Here's my email sender setting in `environment/development.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false    
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.assets.debug = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => 'gmail.com',
    :user_name            => 'my_username',
    :password             => 'my_pass',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
end
```

Here's my `UserMailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base  
    def checkout(admin_email, email, ids, store_name)
        @email = email
        @seller = admin_email
        @store_name = store_name
        @orders = []
        @store = Store.where("name = ?", store_name).first

        ids.each do |f|
          @orders << Order.find(f) 
        end   
        mail(:to => "<#{email}>", :from => "<#{admin_email}>", :subject => "checkout confirmation")
      end
end
```

and here's code in my controller for sending the email:

```
UserMailer.checkout(admin_email, email, ids, store.name).deliver
```

Why is this email seems to be sent, (according to logs) but not sent to recipient?

Comment: why you are write the less and greater then sign before and after of your mail remove them.

Comment: Yea, Change to  `mail(:to => email, :from => admin_email, :subject => "checkout confirmation")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using gmail, make sure your username field is actually: username@gmail.com
i had a similar problem and it worked once i changed the username